# QuickBlox storage limitation

Tags: chat, quickblox, quickblox-android

I would like to use [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/) service in my application. Users can send images/audios/videos to the dialog. QuickBlox [supports](http://quickblox.com/developers/Content) it, but I can't find more information about limitations

1. What is the storage size for files?
2. How long files can store there?
3. What will happen with if storage is full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- storage is unlimited (you are subject to fair usage)
- no expiration date for files
- max file size is 100 mb per one file

Comment: What happens if the plan limits are exceeded ?? Say for plan 'Advanced' we have 35,000 active members and Push notifications :-35/s.. What will happen if we cross the limit of that particular plan ??